# Oracle Apex installation issue

Tags: oracle, installation, config, oracle-apex, epg

`SQL> @apex_epg_config D:\X19`

I am getting an error during installation of oracle apex 19 on window server 2008 with oracle 11gr2

Loading images directory: D:\X19/apex/images
declare

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kzxcInitLoadLocal-7], [64131],
>   [ORA-64131: XMLIndex Metadata: failure during the looking up of the dictionary
>   ORA-30966: error detected in the XML Index layer
>   ORA-30966: error detected in the XML Index layer
>   ], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>   ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 437
>   ORA-06512: at line 65

```
timing for: Load Images
Elapsed: 00:05:40.40
```

Oracle apex status is VALID in dba_registory.

When I open the URL then the following message is displayed.
[apex url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GYOK.png)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to contact oracle support for ora-00600 errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is your version 11.2.0.4 ? This is what the documentation states:

Oracle APEX 19.2 is fully supported through Oracle Support Services on all Editions (EE, SE2, SE, and SE1) of the Oracle database, **11.2.0.4** or higher with a valid Oracle Database Technical Support agreement.

If you have no option to use a different database version ( like 12c or 18c ) my suggestion is that you install a prior version of Apex, like 5.1.4

Without more details regarding your db configuration, I could only find a possible explanation:

**ORA-00600 [kzxcInitLoadLocal-7], [64131], [ORA-64131: XMLIndex Metadata: failure during the looking up of the dictionary (Doc ID 1383658.1)**

The note states that the error is produced by a wrongly database character set change. If this is the case, restore the database backup from prior to the database character set change via the ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET method, then use CSSCAN/CSALTER to change the database character set.